# Open a custom Finder Window on plugging in USB

Tags: finder

I would like to open a custom finder window on plugging in a USB drive without activating any applescript on the Mac. 
I know for sure that it is possible because, I have a USB from VMWare (VMware fusion app) that does the same. As soon as I plug in the Fusion app USB, it opens up a custom finder window.

Could someone help me out with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this? 
http://jordan.broughs.net/archives/2008/03/creating-cross-platform-windows-and-mac-installer-cds

It rounds down to creating a custom .dmg and then burning it to the usb key with the following command `sudo dd if=~/path/to/image.dmg of=/dev/rdisk{N} bs=1m`
where {N} should be replaced with the correct disk number that you can lookup at: `diskutil list`

That's all there is to it.